# Help with logical equivalences and proving tautology

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

I've been wracking my brain trying to figure this out, but I don't know what to do after a certain point.  I'm trying to prove whether or not this is a tautology:
$$
[(p\wedge r)\wedge (p\rightarrow q)]\rightarrow q
$$

So this is what I did (~ is a negation, couldn't figure out how to do a different symbol):
$$
\sim [(p\wedge r)\wedge (p\rightarrow q)]\vee  q
$$
$$
[\sim(p\wedge r)\vee \sim(p\rightarrow q)]\vee  q
$$
$$
[(\sim p\vee \sim r) \vee \sim(p\rightarrow q)]\vee  q
$$
$$
[(\sim p\vee \sim r) \vee \sim(\sim p\vee q)]\vee  q
$$
$$
[(\sim p\vee \sim r) \vee \sim(\sim p\vee q)]\vee  q
$$
$$
[(\sim p\vee \sim r) \vee p\vee \sim q)]\vee  q
$$

I just don't know what to do now, or if I'm even going in the right direction.

Comment: The commands `\lor`, `\land`, and `\lnot` may be helpful in getting the notation you want.

Comment: Are you trying to use natural deduction or tree method specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{You were doing okay, up to here:}&[(\neg p\vee \neg r)\vee\neg (\neg p\vee q)]\vee q
\\[1ex] \text{Associate and Commute:}&[(\neg p\vee q)\vee \neg (\neg p\vee q)]\vee \neg r
\\[1ex] \text{Complement:} & \top\vee \neg r
\\[1ex] \text{Annihilate:}&\top
\end{array}$

And you are done.

---

Via Natural Deduction:
$$\boxed{\begin{array}{l|l:l}
1 & (p\wedge r)\wedge (p\to q) & \textsf{Assume}
\\2 & (p\wedge r) &1, \wedge\mathsf E
\\ 3 & p\to q & 1, \wedge\mathsf E
\\ 4 & p & 2, \wedge\mathsf E
\\ 5 & q & 3,4, \to\mathsf E(MP)
\\ \hline \Box & (p\wedge r) \wedge (p\to q) ~\to~ q & 1, 5, \to\mathsf I(MP)
\end{array}}$$

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (a bit sloppy):

\begin{align*}
 & \left(\left(p\wedge r\right)\wedge\left(p\rightarrow q\right)\right)\rightarrow q\\
= & \neg\left(\left(p\wedge r\right)\wedge\left(\neg p\vee q\right)\right)\vee q\\
= & \left(\neg\left(p\wedge r\right)\vee\neg\left(\neg p\vee q\right)\right)\vee q\\
= & \left(\neg p\vee\neg r\vee\left(p\wedge q\right)\right)\vee q\\
= & \left(\neg p\vee\neg r\vee p\right)\vee q\\
= & 1\vee q
\end{align*}

Alternatively, there's always [the brute force approach](http://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html):

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a bit about what you are doing in the last two steps?  I'm not sure what Law you are using (e.g. Associative, Absorption etc...)

Comment: I guess what I am using is LEM (law of excluded middle). Suppose $q$, then we are done. Suppose $\neg q$, then we can remove the literal $q$ from the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to show that
$$
[(p\wedge r)\wedge (p\rightarrow q)]\rightarrow q
\, \, \bf(1)$$

First we use "simplification" to infer that
$$\textbf{(1)} \implies p \land (p \rightarrow q)$$

Now this is known as "Modus Ponens."

Well, $$p \implies q \iff \neg p \lor q$$

Then we have $$p \land ( \neg p \lor q)$$

if $\neg q$, we have a contradiction.

As an aside, you could use simplification and then use brute force.